# Can you use jquery's :eq() selector twice in the same expression?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to write a table sorter function, so I need to be able to get the HTML of the nth column of the nth row of the table. I tried the following, and it didn't work (it returns null, and that specific column definitely has text inside of it):

```
$('tr:eq(3) td(eq(2)').html()
```

But later in the code, when I use this, it works fine:

```
$('tr:eq(3)').attr('id')
```

Is it not possible to use `:eq()` twice? If it is, am I calling it wrong? If not, is there a way I can do this another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have a `(` instead of a `:` in here:

```
td(eq(2)
```

An alternative is `:nth-child()` which uses 1-based indexing instead of 0-based:

```
$('tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(3)').html()
```

Answer (score 4):

[@BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) has the jQuery fix for you [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877680/can-you-use-jquerys-eq-selector-twice-in-the-same-expression/4877696#4877696).

FYI, you can access row/column easily using native methods.

From the table element, just do `.rows[3].cells[2]`. This will be a very fast way to do a cell lookup.

```
var myTable = $('#theTable')[0];

var html = myTable.rows[3].cells[2].innerHTML;
```